# Find path in tree structure

Tags: postgresql, tree

I have a PostgreSQL 15 table `taxons` with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE taxons (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    parent_id integer,
    name jsonb
);

INSERT INTO taxons VALUES (1, null, '{ "en": "Clothes", "de": "Bekleidung" }');
INSERT INTO taxons VALUES (2, 1, '{ "en": "Men", "de": "Männer" }');
INSERT INTO taxons VALUES (3, 2, '{ "en": "Pants", "de": "Hosen" }');
```

I want to find a specific path by name in this structure, e.g. `Clothes > Men > Pants`. The names could be in any locale of the `name` field.

This is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  t0.* 
FROM 
  taxons t0 
  JOIN taxons t1 ON (
    LOWER(t1.name ->> 'en') = LOWER('clothes') OR LOWER(t1.name ->> 'de') = LOWER('clothes')
  ) 
  AND t1.parent_id IS NULL 
  JOIN taxons t2 ON (
    LOWER(t2.name ->> 'en') = LOWER('MEN') OR LOWER(t2.name ->> 'de') = LOWER('MEN')
  ) 
  AND t2.parent_id = t1.id 
WHERE 
  (
    LOWER(t0.name ->> 'en') = LOWER('Hosen') OR LOWER(t0.name ->> 'de') = LOWER('Hosen')
  ) 
  AND t0.parent_id = t2.id
```

My questions would be:

1. Is there a better way to query the tree structure? I've read something about recursive CTE's, but have a hard time understanding it.
2. Is it possible to use some kind of jsonb function to search within `name` for a match so that I don't have to know all the locales in my query? Some records can have different locales, and sometimes there are more than 5 translations for a name, so the query get's pretty long and unreadable.

Here is a DB Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b28vZrTpRcX5RbhKm4ZvKo/3

Comment: These are two questions. Since it is hard to answer both very different questions in one answer, it is common sense to open two questions on SO. For the first one, see my answer below.

Comment: For your second question, lateral join to `jsonb_each()` to get all the values without the knowing the locales in advance.

Comment: could you providing an example? That would be super helperful to me

Answer (score 1):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RHz3GZu7)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (                       -- 1
    SELECT *, ARRAY[t.name ->> 'de'] as path  -- 3
    FROM taxons t
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL

    UNION                                     -- 2

    SELECT                                    -- 4
        t.*,
        c.path || (t.name ->> 'de')
    FROM taxons t
    JOIN cte c ON c.id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT 
    array_to_string(c.path, ' -> ') as name   -- 5
FROM cte c
```

1. Starting a recursive CTE. A recursive CTE always contains two parts. The starting query and the recursion part.
2. Both parts are devided by the `UNION` clause.
3. This is the start. Here the root record(s) will be found. In your case the root is the record with no parents. Additionally to its columns, I added an array for storing the path. The first element in the path is the current `name`.
4. Now it works similar to what you did. In the first recursion all records are searched which `parent_id` values equal the previously found `id` values (in that case the one of the root record) by doing a `JOIN` operation. The previous result is always represented by the `WITH` clause, so the joining table is `cte` (So, in your case the current step's `table` is taxons, the one for the previous results is `cte`). The next recursion will find the elements with the `parent_id` values equal to the `id` values of the previous recursion and so on. All found records will be appended to the previous records by the `UNION` clause. Additionally all found `name` values will be added to the array, I created in the root step to save the path.
5. Get the entire recursion set afterwards and create the appropriate string from the created path array.